# How would you find and replace values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 5 values. I want to replace the values in this dictionary which are less than a certain value (like 0.10) with another value.

This is what I currently have:

```
stats = {"Apples": 0.30, "Oranges": 0.40, "Pears": 0.25, "Bananas": 0.03, "Grapes": 0.07}
```

In my example, I would like to code in that any fruit less than 0.10 is rounded up to 0.10, so my output in the above example would be:

```
stats = {"Apples": 0.30, "Oranges": 0.40, "Pears": 0.25, "Bananas": 0.10, "Grapes": 0.10}
```

If this were a dataframe, I would be able to use the .mask() function, but is there an equivalent for dictionaries?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there *any* part of this problem whose code you can post?

Comment: you can also do this:
stats = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]) if x[1] > 0.1 else (x[0], 0.1), stats.items()))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
stats = {'Apples': 0.30, 'Oranges': 0.40, 'Pears': 0.25, 'Bananas': 0.03, 'Grapes': 0.07}

for k, v in stats.items():
    if v < 0.1:
        stats[k] = 0.1

print(stats)
```

output :

```
{'Apples': 0.3, 'Oranges': 0.4, 'Pears': 0.25, 'Bananas': 0.1, 'Grapes': 0.1}
```

`0.3` is a float, you can't have `0.30` in the output, unless you want it as a string. (rightmost zeroes have no effect in floats)